# The impact of number of negative samples used in a highly imbalanced dataset (XGBoost)

Tags: machine-learning, xgboost

I am trying to model a classifier using XGBoost on a highly imbalanced data-set, with a limited number of positive samples and practically infinite number of negative samples. 
Is it possible that having too many negative samples (making the data-set even more imbalanced) will weaken the model's predictive power? Is there a reason to limit the number of negative samples aside from running time?

I am aware of the `scale_pos_weight` parameter which should address the issue but my intuition says even this method has its limits.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To answer your question directly: adding more negative examples will likely decrease the decision power of the trained classifier. For the negative class choose the most representative examples and discard the rest.

Learning from imbalanced dataset can influence the predictive power and even an ability of a classifier to converge at all. Generally recommended strategy is to maintain similar sizes of training examples per each of the classes. Imbalance of classes effect on learning depends on the shape of the decision space and the width of boundaries between classes. The wider they are, and the simpler the decision space the more successful training even for imbalanced datasets.

**TL;DR**

For a quick overview of the methods of imbalanced learning I recommend these two articles:

- [SMOTE and AdaSyn by example](https://medium.com/coinmonks/smote-and-adasyn-handling-imbalanced-data-set-34f5223e167)
- [How to Handle Imbalanced Data: An Overview](https://www.datascience.com/blog/imbalanced-data)
- [Dealing with Imbalanced Classes in Machine Learning](https://towardsdatascience.com/dealing-with-imbalanced-classes-in-machine-learning-d43d6fa19d2)
- [Learning from Imbalanced Data](http://www.ele.uri.edu/faculty/he/research/ImbalancedLearning/ImbalancedLearning_lecturenotes.pdf) by Prof. Haibo He (more scientific)

There is a Python package called [`imbalanced-learn`](https://imbalanced-learn.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) which has an extensive documentation of algorithms that I recommend for in-depth review.

Comment: Thank you! I should add that the real-world data is also very imbalanced (probably millions of negatives per one positive). Do I still need to strive for a balanced data-set?

Comment: Unfortunately, the classifier or training procedure does not care about the real-world ratios. In the case you have I would thoroughly explore the links I provided and tried to use the algorithms proposed.